# C function returns 0 when shouldn't

Tags: c, return-value, numerical

I'm making a set of functions in C for simulate a microcanonial ensamble (a periodic-bounded box with N particles with fixed Energy and Volume). The point is that one of my main functions is **to get the distance between 2 particles**, and **sometimes it returns 0 even if the particles are not that close**.

The function is

```
// Determinar la mínima distancia dadas dos coordenadasy una longitud de caja periodica
float pdist(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float a) {
   float Dx = abs(x2-x1);
   float Dy = abs(y2-y1);
   if(Dx >a/2) Dx = a-Dx;
   if(Dy >a/2) Dy = a-Dy;
   return sqrt(pow(Dx,2)+pow(Dy,2));
}
```

If you want to see all the code, you can see it in
https://gitlab.com/jarr.tecn/statistical_mechanics

in the file box.h
and one example in ejemplo.h

Comment: Can you give us an example input, where it returns 0 unexpectedly?

Comment: What is the part with the `if` conditions supposed to do?

Comment: you shouldn't use `pow` for squaring. use `sqrt(Dx*Dx + Dy*Dy)`

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Why is the distance between two particles a function of `a`?

Comment: @halfer: Do feel empowered to correct obvious mistakes in English; perhaps respecting the fact that English might not be the native language of the OP.

Comment: How do you know it is zero? If you are debugging then you should be able to work though the issue. If not, then it may not be equal to zero, it may be you are printing a very small number. Does the return fail the the test (pdist() == 0.0)

Comment: Are you using very small numbers? You may want to use doubles. Also pick sensible units as you may be running out of range. Remember you are squaring so you need double the number of places for the intermediate calculation.

Comment: @Bathsheba: of course. I was asking because I genuinely was unsure how to correct it. Sometimes it is worth checking, rather than veering the question's text away from the author's intended meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from [`abs`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/abs) function which will return an integer:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float pdist(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float a) {
    float Dx = abs(x2-x1);
    float Dy = abs(y2-y1);
    if(Dx >a/2) Dx = a-Dx;
    if(Dy >a/2) Dy = a-Dy;
    return sqrt(pow(Dx,2)+pow(Dy,2));
}

float pdist2(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float a) {
    float Dx = fabsf(x2-x1);
    float Dy = fabsf(y2-y1);
    if(Dx >a/2) Dx = a-Dx;
    if(Dy >a/2) Dy = a-Dy;
    return sqrt(pow(Dx,2)+pow(Dy,2));
 }

int main(void)
{
    printf("first form: %f\n", pdist(.1, .1, .2, .2, .5));
    printf("second form: %f\n", pdist2(.1, .1, .2, .2, .5));
}
```

Gives:

```
first form: 0.000000
second form: 0.141421
```